# Double side integration of Drupal 7x And Moodle 2X?

Tags: php, drupal-7, integration, drupal-modules, moodle

Hello guys Is there possible to Integrate Drupal 7X and Moodle 2x from both side
like. User create in drupal its also login with same name in moodle and user create in moodle its also login with the same name in drupal . I integrated one side drupal to moodle.But can't fiend how to do double side integration can any one help mi if that possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For authentication through other db Moodle provide great auth plugin called External database (http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/External_database_authentication).

You can fill your drupal db detail in the setting and authenticate the same users which is created in drupal.

Hope it will help you.